# Convert PCM to AAC while streaming

Tags: python, http-live-streaming, pcm, aac, g.711

I'm looking to use Python to convert audio that's in PCM (G.711U to be specific) to AAC so it can be streamed using HLS. What options are there for doing this conversion in memory so the streaming can be continued in real-time.

Comment: pydub https://pydub.com   I haven't used it personally but heard its good.

Comment: `pydub` seems interesting but it only appears to work on files. I need to be able to do this with data in memory

Answer (score 1):

Low level access to ffmpeg with a python binding should do it.

I'd try https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python

Comment: This appears to be a wrapper around running `ffmpeg` commands and doesn't give access to the raw data that I can feed into it and get back out